# PHP merge arrays by matching last character of array key

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress

I'm retrieving form data using SQL and displaying this with PHP. The fields appear as `qualification_0` and `qualification_type_0`, the only value changing being the number so I would like to group these values into one array that I can then display into the correct inputs.

Inputs can be removed by the user so the numbers will not always increment by 1, but will always be sent as a pair.

**Currently**

The data appears as:

```
Array
(
    [qualification_0] => Karate
    [qualification_2] => Test
    [qualification_type_0] => Course
    [qualification_type_2] => Certificate
)
```

**Goal**

I'm trying to achieve the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qualification_0] => Karate
            [qualification_type_0] => Course
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [qualification_2] => Test
            [qualification_type_2] => Certificate
        )
)
```

**My code**

SQL/PHP:

```
    public function getAllSelfDevelopments()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "usermeta";
        $result = $wpdb->get_results(
            "
            SELECT meta_key, meta_value
            FROM $table_name
            WHERE user_id = $this->user_id
            AND meta_key LIKE 'qualification%'
            ", ARRAY_A
        );

        return $result;
    }
```

Query Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => qualification_0
            [meta_value] => Karate
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => qualification_2
            [meta_value] => Test
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => qualification_type_0
            [meta_value] => Course
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [meta_key] => qualification_type_2
            [meta_value] => Certificate
        )

)
```

Attempt:

```
    $self_developments = $candidate->getAllSelfDevelopments();

    $self_developments_arr = [];
    foreach($self_developments as $value){
        $self_developments_arr[$value['meta_key']] = $value['meta_value'];
    }

    $self_dev = [];
    foreach($self_developments_arr as $key => $value){

        if(strpos($key, $key[-1]) !== FALSE && !in_array($key, $self_dev)){
            $self_dev[] = [
                $key => $value
            ];
        }

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you to your goal. It involves some advanced use of regular expressions.

```
//Load in meta data
$self_developments = $candidate->getAllSelfDevelopments();

//Create container for results
$results = [];
foreach($meta_values as $meta) {

    //Create Named matching groups that go into $matches. See PHP docs for details.
    preg_match('/(?P<key>.+)_(?P<index>\d+)/',$meta['meta_key'], $matches);

    //Use our index value to act as a guide to place our data. If the index does not exist, make it an empty array.
    //Otherwise, merge in our existing data with the new data.
    $results[$matches['index']] = array_merge($results[$matches['index']] ?? [], [$meta['meta_key'] => $meta['meta_value']]);

}
//if you want to re-index the array.
$results = array_values($results);
```

Should output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qualification_0] => Karate
            [qualification_type_0] => Course
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qualification_2] => Test
            [qualification_type_2] => Certificate
        )

)
```

Or, if you elected to re-index:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [qualification_0] => Karate
            [qualification_type_0] => Course
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [qualification_2] => Test
            [qualification_type_2] => Certificate
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just had to change the $meta_values to $self_developments.  This is so much better than the four loops I had!

Comment: Ah, my bad there. I copy/pasted that line and forgot to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Could this solution be a solution?

```php
$array = [
    'qualification_0' => 'Karate',
    'qualification_2' => 'Test',
    'qualification_type_0' => 'Course',
    'qualification_type_2' => 'Certificate',
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('~(.+)_(\d+)~', $key, $match);
    ${$match[1]}[$match[2]] = $value;
}

$result = array_combine($qualification, $qualification_type);
print_r($result);
```

it will output:

```php
Array                                                                                                                                                     
(                                                                                                                                                         
    [Karate] => Course                                                                                                                                    
    [Test] => Certificate                                                                                                                                 
)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!  This PHP code looks quite advanced, I'm not quite sure what the ${match} line is doing or how the $result is detecting variables that don't exist.

This is close to what I'm trying to achieve but please see my 'Goal' (second code block) for the result I'm trying to achieve.